# Get installed application list in UWP

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile

I have an application that needs to reads name of all installed app on user mobile. but i can't do that.
How can i get list of installed applications in Universal Windows Platform on windows 10 mobile?

thanks for your helping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP` and use the following code:

```
if (ApiInformation.IsTypePresent("Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager"))
{
    var packages = Windows.Phone.Management.Deployment.InstallationManager.FindPackages();
    foreach (var package in packages)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(package.DisplayName);
    }
}
```

But this code requires `ID_CAP_OEM_DEPLOYMENT`. As I know from [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d1da5cdd-1f12-4f4d-b781-92948b518543/idcapoemdeployment-working-on-emulator-but-not-on-real-device?forum=wpdevelop)

> I would assume that you would require a company certificate and would have to sign your Apps with that certificate in order for those permissions to work.

Comment: Yes - you need to be specifically whitelisted by Microsoft to do this.