# How to get list of installed Windows Universal Apps?

Tags: windows, winapi, win-universal-app

Im trying to make a launcher program that launches Windows Apps.
I can find Win32 Applications but I have no idea for how to find UWP Apps (Universal Apps).
Is there any API or Directories for listing Universal Apps?

Comment: possible duplicate [Get installed application list in UWP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293051/get-installed-application-list-in-uwp)

Comment: Use the [PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.aspx) class from the [Windows.Management.Deployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.management.deployment.aspx) namespace. Sample code can be found at [Enumerate app packages sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/package-manager-inventory-ee821079).

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks!

Comment: No one wants to launch universal apps anyway ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't use the PackageManager class mentioned in the above comments inside a UWP app.

Can you use powershell? If so, there is

```
    Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

which will list all the app packages (.appx) installed (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx).

See this MSDN question for more details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/b20cef2c-98a8-4d6f-8231-db856199f2c9/uwppossible-to-get-installed-packages-in-uwp10-across-all-users?forum=wpdevelop

Comment: From [Get-AppxPackage](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856044.aspx): *"To get the list of packages for a user profile other than the profile for the current user, you must run this command by using administrator permissions."*